# Codeigniter how to echo more than one INNER JOIN from same table

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, inner-join

I am new to Codeigniter and I have been at this for the last three days and have reached a dead end. I am running the following query to get the fixture details from the table.

I have got two tables team and fixture which have a many to many relationship which results in a Join table called team_has _fixture

Below are my tables

```
 team

 team_id
 team_name
 team_logo


 fixture

 fixture_id
 fixture_text
 fixture_comp
 fixture_type
 fixture_level
 fixture_date


 team_has_fixture

 team_team_id
 team_fixture_id
 team_team_id2
```

This is a sample of code from my MODEL

MODEL

```
$results = array();

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('team_has_fixture as tf');

$this->db->join('team as t1', 'tf.team_team_id = t1.team_id');
$this->db->join('team as t2', 'tf.team_team_id2 = t2.team_id');
$this->db->join('fixture', 'tf.fixture_fixture_id = fixture.fixture_id');

$query = $this->db->get();

   if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
     {
      $results = $query->result();
     }

        return $results;
```

I am trying to create a fixture that features the logo for two teams in it but when I run this code only one logo displays.

All of the fixture details are retrieved correctly but only one of the team logos is retrieved and I need both logos.

The following two lines from my Model code to retrieve the data overwrite each other which results in only the second line working.

```
 $this->db->join('team as t1', 'tf.team_team_id = t1.team_id');
 $this->db->join('team as t2', 'tf.team_team_id2 = t2.team_id');
```

If I comment out the second line the first line brings back all the details for the fixture and the first teams logo. If I dont comment out the second line the query brings back all the fixture details and the second teams logo - it seems to overwrite the line above it

I have searched on here and other sources for a solution and am really stuck with this and would appreciate any help.

I am also unsure how to call for the second logo to be displayed in my view.

The code to display the results in my view is

VIEW

```
<?php

     if (is_array($results))
     {
       if( !empty($results) ) 
       {
        foreach($results as $row) 
       {

          echo '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">';
          echo '<div class="thumbnail">';

          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<h4>';
          echo '<td>'.$row->fixture_type.'</td>'."</br></br>";

          echo '<td>'.'<img src="'."$row->team_logo".'">  '.$row->fixture_text.'   <img src="'."$row->team_logo".'"> '.'</td>'."</br></br>";

          echo '<td>'.$row->fixture_level.'</td>'."</br></br>";
          echo '<td>'.$row->fixture_comp.'</td>'."</br>";
          echo '</h4>';

          echo '<td>'.$row->fixture_date.'</td>'."</br></br>";
          echo '</tr>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';
         }
       }
```

Using  echo $this->db->last_query(); to display my last query I get the following

```
SELECT * FROM (`team_has_fixture` as tf) JOIN `team` as t1 ON `t1`.`team_id` =  `tf`.`team_team_id` JOIN `fixture` ON `tf`.`fixture_fixture_id` = `fixture`.`fixture_id`
```

Using var_dump($query->result()); to display the results of my query I get the following

```
[0]=> object(stdClass)#22 (15) 

{ 

["team_team_id"]=> string(1) "5" 
["fixture_fixture_id"]=> string(2) "62" 
["team_team_id2"]=> string(2) "15" 
["team_id"]=> string(2) "15" 
["team_name"]=> string(8) "Kilkenny" 
["team_logo"]=> string(25) "../../crests/kilkenny.png" 
["fixture_id"]=> string(2) "62" 
["fixture_text"]=> string(16) "Clare V Kilkenny" 
["fixture_type"]=> string(7) "Hurling" 
["fixture_comp"]=> string(36) "Allianz Hurling League 2014 Roinn 1A" 
["fixture_round"]=> string(7) "Round 1" 
["fixture_level"]=> string(8) "Roinn 1A" 
["fixture_time"]=> string(3) "2pm" 
["fixture_date"]=> string(26) "Sunday February 16th, 2014" 
["fixture_venue_id"]=> string(1) "5" 

}
```

As you can see I get one of the team logos but not the other one. This is the problem I am trying to solve. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: add `echo $this->db->last_query();` after `$query = $this->db->get();` and add query in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining `team` table twice, that means your select got same column name thats why one column is overwriting the other column value as they are same name, so you should change all of your `t2` alias with new column name. See the example

```
$this->db->select('tf.*, t1.*, t2.team_id as team_id_2, t2.COL_NAME as COL_NAME_2,......');
```

so you will get all different index for the t2 table

Comment: I have tried this and it gives a syntax error. `$this->db->select('tf.*, t1.*, t2.team_id as team_id_2, t2.team_name as t2.team_name_2, t2.team_logo as t2.team_logo_2');`

Comment: `$this->db->select('tf.*, t1.*, t2.team_id as team_id_2, t2.team_name as team_name_2, t2.team_logo as team_logo_2');` Not the t2.team_logo_2

Comment: when you say `t2.COL_NAME as SHOULD_BE_A_NAME_ONLY` you cannot say `t2.NEW_NAME` becaues NEW_NAME is not in t2 yet you are giving a new column name, by mistake i added t2 on my example

Comment: Minhaz Ahmed Thank you so much - you have solved it :) I really appreciate your help